# Java Decompiler for Eclipse (JD-Eclipse) not running in Ganymede

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, decompiler, ganymede

I have installed JD-Eclipse in many platforms and it works fine. I have a platform which the installation does not work. Please identify exactly what versions of each product must be installed.  Note: I have carefully reviewed the installation requirements and reinstalled eclipse on the destination platform. Also this is a different question from the JD Eclipse not running in Helios as the requirements are not the same.

Comment: I know that JAD is no longer supported, but I found jadclipse to be more stable than JD-Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [JD-Eclipse Prerequisites](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse)

Comment: I installed v3.4 prerequisites first. I have reinstalled several times. the only failure consistency is that the decompiler plugin doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I make some tests on the installation of the plugin from the JD-Eclipse Update site :

- Eclipse Ganymede / Windows / JD-Eclipse 0.1.3 : OK
- Eclipse Ganymede / Linux / JD-Eclipse 0.1.3 : OK
- Eclipse Ganymede / OSX / JD-Eclipse 0.1.3 : KO ! The    plugin is partially downloaded.
- Eclipse Indigo / OSX / JD-Eclipse 0.1.3 : OK

Workaround:
Download the offline Update site ([jdeclipse_update_site.zip](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-eclipse/update/jdeclipse_update_site.zip)) and copy the files "jd.ide.eclipse_0.1.3.jar" and "jd.ide.eclipse.macosx.x86(_64)_0.1.3.jar" in your "plugins" folder.

Comment: thx for reply. Still problem plugin. i.e. problem with Equinox p2 Provisioning, 1.0.2.r34x_v2009120 installed and err on attempt to update  
Cannot complete the request.  See the details.
Equinox p2 Provisioning is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot find a solution where both Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.generator/[1.0.4.v20081217,1.0.4.v20081217]] and Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.generator/[1.0.0.v20080604,1.0.0.v20080604]] can be satisfied.

Comment: I performed another clean install with eclipse-jee-ganymede-SR2-win32 version. Then I manually installed jd-Eclipse from jdeclipse_update_site.zip. The 3 jar files were installed by unpacking them: Feature file in feature directory under jd.edi.eclipse.feature_0.1.3 folder and in plugins directory two new folders jd.ide.eclipse_0.1.3 and jd.ide.eclipse.win32.x86_0.1.3. Verified two plugins installed under help->About Eclipse Platform. I do not see any log errors. Please advise.